# How to BURN an ERC721 token without an owner permission

Tags: nft, burn

Guys.

I am running a NFT project, and while implementing the contract of the token, I am curious about **how to burn ERC721 tokens without the authority of the owner.**

Can the project operator arbitrarily burn the owner's token using the ERC721 burnable authority?

I'd appreciate it if you could attach a document for reference.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to implement something like this. But you will likely have to override the native `transferFrom()/burn()` functions found in ERC721 to modify its functionality to allow you such a thing.

In short, it is doable, but you need to program-in such functionality.

For example: You can make it so that the owner of the ECR721 contract can burn user NFT's with or without their permissions.

Answer (score 0):

generally it the burn function is not enabled you have to use another address like : 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD
generally contracts prevent the usage of address 0.
this one should works